# How to read an attribute's value in a custom Struts2 tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, esapi, custom-tag

I am customizing the Struts2 `<s:property>` tag.

I've created a new attribute, `encrypt`; when it's set to `true`, it forces the encryption of the `<s:property />`'s value with an [ESAPI library](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Esapi).

The question is: how can I read the value of the custom `encrypt` attribute ?

jsp :

```
<input type="radio" id="selection" style="width: 20px;" name="convocazioneUtenteSistemaMotorizzazioneView.utenteFrom.progressivoUtent‌​e" class="zeroborder" value="<s:property encrypt="true" value="#attr['listConvocazioneUtenteSistemaMotorizzazione'].progressivoUtente" />"
```

in Java , Can I get the value of "encrypt?"

Comment: It's all here: https://bodez.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/customising-struts2-jsp-tags/

Comment: Post a code you have tried so far.

Comment: jsp : <input type="radio" id="selection" style="width: 20px;"
   name="convocazioneUtenteSistemaMotorizzazioneView.utenteFrom.progressivoUtente"  class="zeroborder" value="<s:property encrypt="true" value="#attr['listConvocazioneUtenteSistemaMotorizzazione'].progressivoUtente" />"                 in Java , Can I get the value of "encrypt" ?

Comment: This is the JSP usage, the tip of the iceberg. The 90% of the code must be written server-side, following the tutorial I've posted above.

Comment: A Problem is another... if I want encrypt a Integer  field , it becomes String...then with a TypeConverter I must convert String to Integer with a decrypt of value...but a library Esapi hasn't a method isEncrypted...then my idea is read the value of "encrypt" from jsp...

Comment: When adding information pleas edit the question; code of any size is illegible in a comment.

Comment: Echoing the other comments, we cannot help you unless you also include your server side code that is talking with your jsp.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Double quotes in the tag cause the error.If you code in the advanced IDE,it will show the something wrong in the tag